# How to save words as dictionary keys with arbitrary integer values?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, tokenize

After tokenizing words, I am trying to figure out how to save them as keys in a dictionary and assign arbitrary integer values.

#### Attempt

```python
import sys 
import re  
    
filename = sys.argv[1]
        
infile = open(filename, 'r')
    
for line in infile:    
    allwords = line.split()

    for word in allwords:
        word = word.rstrip('.:;!,"?)_')
        book = {word.lower()}   

print(book)
```

Comment: what is the point to keep them as dict ? You will throw away duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

## Dictionary comprehension with random values

One solution would be to use a dictionary comprehension and assign random integer values.

```
import random

words_test = ['hello', 'world', 'goodbye', 'tomorrow']
book = {word: random.randint(0, 1000) for word in words_test}

print(book)
```

#### Output

```
{'hello': 318, 'world': 576, 'goodbye': 699, 'tomorrow': 847}
```

## Same integer value using `dict.fromkeys()`

If the integer values do not need to be random, you could also use:

```
words_test = ['hello', 'world', 'goodbye', 'tomorrow']
book = dict.fromkeys(words_test, 1)

print(book)
```

#### Output

```
{'hello': 1, 'world': 1, 'goodbye': 1, 'tomorrow': 1}
```

## Loop that adds a key-value pair per iteration

```
words_test = ['hello', 'world', 'goodbye', 'tomorrow']

book = dict()
for word in words_test:
    book[word] = 1

print(book)
```

#### Output

```
{'hello': 1, 'world': 1, 'goodbye': 1, 'tomorrow': 1}
```

Comment: We love that attempt! The thing is, we can't use random and the words are idk how many so we can't manually create the dict. We have the book tokenized though, just need to add all those words to a dict and assign one integer as a value. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @LonelyRanger05 See updated answer with two additional options. I am not sure why the number of words would matter when creating a dictionary. Perhaps you could clarify?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> book = {word.lower()}
> ```

This is creating a set of one item, not a dictionary.

Create the dictionary before the loop. Then set the value using the notation `dict_name[key]=value` to set the key-value pairs:

```
import sys 
import re
import random

filename = sys.argv[1]
    
infile = open(filename, 'r')

book = {}

for line in infile:
    allwords = line.split()

    for word in allwords:
        word = word.rstrip('.:;!,"?)_')
        book[word.lower()] = random.randint(0,1000)

print(book)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the logic of the question so I come with 2 other options:

import random
form collections import Counter

```
words_test = ['hello', 'world', 'goodbye', 'tomorrow','jack','jack']
```

## option 1 - by Christopher Peisert

```
book = {word: random.randint(0, 1000) for word in words_test}
```

## option 2 - use set - duplicates will be removed

```
words_set = set(words_test)
```

## option 3 - use counter. see

```
# https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

counter = Counter(words_test)
```